# is there any remote desktop tool from Microsoft which is similar to Royal TS

Tags: remote-desktop

is there any remote desktop tool from Microsoft which is similar to Royal TS (apart from MSTSC )

Answer (score 2):

I have never used Royal TS, but I looked at the screenshots, and it reminds me of something, so I hope this helps.

I wouldn't say it is publically released, but one of the Microsoft MVPS [on the Exchange blog](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2010/06/11/455115.aspx) talked about an internal tool called Remote Desktop Connection Manager, which can do similar things.

It is freely available from the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4603c621-6de7-4ccb-9f51-d53dc7e48047).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop Connection manager is available through [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/site1049).

Update: [direct link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4603c621-6de7-4ccb-9f51-d53dc7e48047) to download, no windows live login required.

Answer (score 0):

It's not from Microsoft, but you may want to take a look at [Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that Royal TS has become commercial, [version 1.5](http://download.code4ward.net/c4w/files/rts-1.5.1/royaltsinstaller.msi) is still freeware.